# Generics vs. Method Overloading

Tags: java, generics

I have 3 methods:

```
//1 -- check one item
public static <T> void containsAtLeast(String message,
                                       T expectedItem,
                                       Collection<? extends T> found) {
    if (!found.contains(expectedItem))
        Assert.fail("...");        
}

//2 -- check several items
public static <T> void containsAtLeast(String message,
                                       Collection<? extends T> expectedItems,
                                       Collection<T> found) {
    for (T exptetedItem : expectedItems)
        containsAtLeast(message, exptetedItem, found);        
}

//3 -- check several items, without message parameter
public static <T> void containsAtLeast(Collection<? extends T> expectedItems,
                                       Collection<? extends T> found) {
    containsAtLeast(null, expectedItems, found);
}
```

I would expect that the method `//3` invoke `//2`  but it does not, it invoke method `//1`. Is there a mistake in what I expect?

*I use sdk 1.7.0_25 and Eclipse 4.3*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your second method expects the generic type of `expectedItems` (`? extends T`) to be a subtype of the generic type of `found` (`T`).

In your third method, there is no subtype relationship between the two generic types. They both extend `T` but could be siblings for example.

So the second method can't be called.

Example: imagine you call the third method with those types:

```
containsAtLeast(Collection<Integer> e, Collection<String> f)
```

So the `T` in your third method is `Object`. And your first method is called with `T = Object` too.

Comment: And additionally, `T` is a per-method type parameter in this case, so all three declarations of it are basically independent of each other.

Comment: But why is the first method called then? If `T` in `\\1` is the same as `Collection<? extends T>` in `\\3`, then `found` in `\\1` must be of type `Collection<? extends <Collection<? extends T>>` in `\\3`? Where am I wrong?

Comment: @assylias: Thank you: I complete overlooked this detail. - So after adding `<? extends T>` for `found` in `//2` it starts working like expected